# How do we know if learning some of the new words are necessary or a waste of energy?

Tags: vocabulary

Sometimes I  receive emails with the name " word of the day" ,but I don’t know how understandable this words are for the others, if I search it on   Google Ngram tool  I still don’t know this site receives  the statistic from the  books or other means to find out how often it is used by ordinary people,please tell me  what I am suppose to do ?

Comment: Learning new words is NEVER a waste of time and energy!

Comment: in order To learn a new  word I have to spend some times and practice it in the sentences and use it in my conversation or perhaps in my writing'  so if I  spend so much time and wouldn't be familiar word' how does it benefit me' instead I could have used the time and learn a useful word.

Comment: How many of the over 1 000 000 words already existing in English do you still not know? OED only lists 60% of them. And I wouldn't think it sensible to trawl through there, collecting even modern additions such as blobfish, flexitarian or wackadoodle. Read good novels. Improve your grammar, style and interpersonal skills (and probably general knowledge) simultaneously. Look up the words you're not sure about.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be careful as to words suggested as the word of the day. They are often very academic and not used in normal everyday language.  Modern dictionaries give hints about the frequency of words.

So the Longman Dictionary of Contempory English has indications such as S2 W3 meaning the word is one of the 2000 most common words in spoken English, or W3 means the word is one of the 3000 most common words in written English.

If the word is not in the DCE you can be sure that it is not contemporary English.

Have a look at take in the DCE. take1 verb has the frequency W1 S1.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take_1

Comment: If you want to know the frequency with which an English word is used, you can also check out the fun tool at Wordcount.org. "Wordcount data currently comes from the British National Corpus®, a 100 million word collection of samples of written and spoken language from a wide range of sources, designed to represent an accurate cross-section of current English usage." http://www.wordcount.org/main.php

Comment: 'If the word is not in the DCE you can be sure that it is not contemporary English.' Even _I_, anti-do-it-yourself-word freak that I'm portrayed as, don't accept _that_.

Comment: ... It doesn't even have 'selfie'!

Comment: the word of the day for today was famulus, at this moment when I typed it even gave me error right here but when I typed in onelook site  offered me several dictionaries some of the words are in two or three dictionaries only .

Comment: I would say it is a rare word, Latin, a historical term for a special servant. If English is a foreign language for you you won't find that word in the next time. I think you have to read Ģoethe's Faust to find that word. I would learn words by reading novels and not from lists.